# C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Instantiating Class within a List?

Tags: c#, list, object, collections, encapsulation

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public string ProductName { get; private set; }
    public decimal LatestPrice { get; private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }
    public decimal TotalOrder { get {return LatestPrice * Quantity;}}

    public OrderItem(string name, decimal price, int quantity)
    {

    }

    public OrderItem(string name, decimal price) : this(name, price, 1)
    {

    }
}
```

Above is the class, just for some background.

```
public void AddProduct(string name, decimal price, int quantity)
{
    lstOrderitem.Add(new OrderItem(name, price, quantity));           
}
```

On the code inside the AddProduct method is where I am getting the error stated in the title.

I'm just trying to instantiate the class and add it to a collection to be displayed in a listbox on my form program.

The "AddProduct" will be called on a button click event

> Error = NullReferenceException - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I was wondering if anybody knew why this was happening since I thought that since I am making a NEW instance of the class while adding it to the list that it would have something to reference too. Thank you if anybody knows what the problem is.

Edit

```
    public List<OrderItem> lstOrderitem{ get; private set; }
    public int NumberOfProducts { get; private set; }
    public decimal BasketTotal { get; private set; }

    public ShoppingBasket()
    {
        //List<OrderItem> lstOrderitem = new List<OrderItem>();
    }

    public void AddProduct(string name, decimal price, int quantity)
    {
        lstOrderitem.Add(new OrderItem(name, price, quantity));


    }
```

Comment: Use the debugger, this should help you in the future.

Comment: `//List<OrderItem> lstOrderitem = new List<OrderItem>();` was almost correct: you should remove `//List<OrderItem>` part to make it an initialization of a member property rather than a local declaration.

Comment: Ahh Okay ill try all of this and get back to you thanks guys for helping me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should initialize `lstOrderitem` property in the constructor, like this:

**EDIT**

```
public MyClass() {
    lstOrderitem = new List<OrderItem>();
}
```

P.S. Microsoft suggests starting the names of your properties in capital letters, to avoid confusion with member variables, which should be named starting with a lowercase letter.

Comment: The "lstOrderItem is a property sorry I should have included that part. Edited the OP to show this

Comment: @Taelmit: even if this is a `auto` property you have to initialize it, like an answer provided and you did.

Comment: Why the compiler doesn't complain when we try to use an instance property that has not been initialized?

Comment: @JayJay Because compiler implicitly initializes instance properties, making sure that there is no such thing as an instance property that has not been initialized.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you didn't initialize your reference `lstOrderitem`. Debug your code if your references value is `null`, you need to initialize `lstOrderitem` before using it.

Comment: The "lstOrderItem is a property sorry I should have included that part.
Edited the OP to show this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't initialize your reference *lstOrderitem*. Debug your code if your reference value is **null**, you need to initialize *lstOrderitem* before using it.

```
public MyClass() {
    lstOrderitem = new List<OrderItem>();
}
```