# Adding to a list returns null

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am working on a system where users can buy items from a shop. Each user is listed in a database, and when they buy that item it should add it to the list `ownedItems` in the database, however when executing the line of the code to add the item it's returning

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

`userAccount` refers to the users section in the database. This is where the item is added to the list, inside of the `!buy` command, which then returns null:

```
    var userAccount = UserAccounts.GetAccount(Context.User);                    
    userAccount.ownedItems.Add(":motorbike: motorbike");
    UserAccounts.SaveAccounts();
```

This is where the list is defined under the class `UserAccount`

```
public List<string> ownedItems { get; set; }
```

This is where the list would be created if the `userAccount` does not exist for the specified user:

```
       private static UserAccount CreateUserAccount(ulong id)
    {
        var newAccount = new UserAccount()
        {
            ID = id,
            Level = 0,
            XP = 0,
            RequiredXP = 150,
            Bank = 50,
            Cash = 50,
            ownedItems = new List<string> { ":iphone: iPhone"  }, //this is where ownedItems is defined
        };

        accounts.Add(newAccount);
        SaveAccounts();
        return newAccount;
    }
```

Although it is set to add ":iphone: iPhone" when a `userAccount` is created, it doesn't. It just sets it to `null`.

```
public static void SaveAccounts()
{
    DataStorage.SaveUserAccounts(accounts, accountsFile);
}

public static void SaveUserAccounts(IEnumerable<UserAccount> accounts, string filePath)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accounts, Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
}
```

Comment: One says `ownedItems1`, the other `ownedItems`, is this how it is? Please always include enough actual code, not just single lines. Preferably a [mcve] so we can see exactly what’s happening

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I have formatted the code better, added some more of it for context and removed my mistake with `ownedItems` where it said `ownedItems`. I am not sure if I can provide a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, as it involves multiple different classes and other sections of code to make it work.

Comment: Do you know, that [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) is **the most** frequent question on C# stackoverflow? Do you have try to do anything before posting this question?

Comment: Yes, but it is defined here so I don't understand why it is appearing as null.

`List<string> ownedItems = new  List<string> { ":iphone: iPhone"  },`

Comment: Does your code compile? It doesn't look like it does. `Cash = 50,",` is definitely wrong, and so is the `List<string> ` part of `List<string> ownedItems`

Comment: I bet your `userAccount.ownedItems == null`. Your `userAccount` is returned from `UserAccounts.GetAccount(..)` method. `List<string> ownedItems = new  List<string>` - is from **another** method (not `UserAccounts.GetAccount(..)`). Why do you think that setting some property of some object in one method will affect same property in **another** object in **another** method?

Comment: Yep it complies. Apologies, I must have made a mistake when pasting and formatting the code as the `",` bit after `Cash = 50,` isn't in the actual code.
What is wrong with the ``List<String>`` bit?

`List<string> ownedItems = new List<string>` is from the method in the card where a `userAccount` would be created if it did not exist

Comment: Is the following line "the actual code"? If so, why do you think `ownedItems` works differently to `ID`, `Level`, `XP`, etc? Does `ownedItems` even exist on `UserAccount`?

Comment: For me it [doesn't compile](https://rextester.com/XNFEI32457). it states: _"(29:28) Invalid expression term 'string'"_ because of the erroneous `List<string> ` before `ownedItems = `

Comment: Yes the following line is part of the actual code. `ownedItems` does exist on UserAccount, I have shown it being added. I am not sure why it works differently to `ID` or `Level` or any of the others.

Comment: Apologies, I am getting confused whilst trying different things to fix it.
`List<string>` is not supposed to be before `ownedItems`. I have edited the code so what you are seeing is the exact code I am using.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Your code [works](https://rextester.com/FZH30895) without the `accounts.Add` and `SaveAccounts`, so perhaps the save is modifying it somehow. I'm not familiar with how the `discord.net` library works, so what the save is doing is outside my area of expertise, I'm afraid. It's definitely not a problem with declaring the list, however.

Comment: Ok I have learnt my lesson to make everything as clear as possible from now on.
Save isn't part of the discord.net library, it is just a method that takes what has been written and writes it to the json file. 


I have added some extra code to the original code above on how the save works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Instantiating Class within a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701846/c-sharp-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-instantiating-clas)

Comment: Is it `GetAccount` thats returning null? So by accessing the `userAccount` it is that which is throwing the null reference rather than the collection

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you format the list as following:

`List<string> ownedItems1 = new List<String>();
ownedItems1.Add("What you want in your list");`

Comment: What does this do that OP's method doesn't do? How does this solve OP's problem?

Comment: You didn't change anything. Same code different implementation!